# who to write function to generate coordinates

Tags: algorithm

I was asked this question during a technical interview, however, was not able to solve it after spending some time. The pattern below represents values along x and y axis --

```
   11 
   7  12
   4  8  13
   2  5  9  14 
   1  3  6  10  15
```

So from the above if

```
(0.0)--->1
(1,0)--->3
(1,1)--->5 
(2,2)--->13
```

and so on...

So what should be the implementation of this method which generates the points

```
int getPoint(int x,int y) {

 }
```

It should give 1, for 0,0; 3 for 1,0 etc as shown above. Any help here appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely, the numbers increase in the following sequence
`(0, 0) -> (0, 1) -> (1, 0) -> (0, 2) -> (1, 1) -> (2, 0) -> (0, 3)  -> (1, 2) -> (2, 1) -> (3, 0) -> ...`
The numbers along a diagonal increase linearly. These numbers have same Manhattan distance `(x+y)`. In one such diagonal the distance increase as x is increased. So we just need to calculate how many points there are below this diagonal and then add `x+1` (`+1` because it increases at `x=0`) to it. Calculating points below the diagonal with Manhattan distance `d` is easy because its just
`1 + 2 + 3 + ... + d = d *(d+1)/2`.
For example to calculate `(3, 1)` we follow this steps:
`d = 3 + 1 = 4`
points below diagonal `4 = 4*5/2 = 10`
Value at `(4, 2) = 10 + 3 + 1 = 14`

Code:

```
int getPoint(int x, int y) {
    int d = x + y;
    return d * (d + 1) / 2 + x + 1;
}
```